# Cygwin not diplaying output from mysql

Tags: mysql, cygwin

When running "mysql -u  -D  -p -h " I do not get the password promt. When running with password on the commend line I do not get the mysql prompt.

I can issue the quit command and mysql exits normally.

ls/ls -al and ping works fine. mysql is in path.

Comment: Is cygwin mysql or a windows version ?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.